# Accessing applicataion bar from non UI class windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, application-bar

In my windows phone app I've a non-UI class which will show and hide a pop up screen when called from the UI page.

I want to hide the application bar when the pop up is shown and show the appbar again when the pop up is closed.

Now the challenge here is I've a timer in the non UI class which handles the closing of the pop up. So from the UI class I can only start the pop up. Closing is controlled by the non UI class. So now I need to access the appbar from the non UI class.

Can any one help me if I can do it or any work around if this cannot be done. ?

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing your UI at all from your non-UI class, because it's a non-UI class.  It should just signaling to a UI class that *it* should update the UI, such as through an event, callback, etc.  How, specifically, can vary depending on context.

Comment: Its quite complex in my case because the class is used by many of the UI pages. So signalling is difficult. Is there a possibility to make this possible ?

Comment: Yes, there is.  As I said, it should fire an event, accept a callback, return a `Task`, or some other comparable asynchronous mechanism whereby the UI can update *itself* at the appropriate time.

Comment: Can you provide me some link or something to learn in detail about it ?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2013/11/25/Update-Creating-a-custom-MessageBox-for-your-Windows-Phone-apps.aspx), it does exactly what you are trying to do. Search for `ApplicationBar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe making use of [Popup.Closed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.closed%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) would help:

```
private void myPopup_Close(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // get current Page
   var currentPage = ((App.Current as App).RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
    // hide popup
    currentPage.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: @Presse You are welcome. Note only that it's the code above is very simple and it should be improved. [Shawn Kendrot added nice link](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2013/11/25/Update-Creating-a-custom-MessageBox-for-your-Windows-Phone-apps.aspx) where you can find much information.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check for sure.